# Latex symbol for Z transform

Tags: symbols

I'd like to write "the $Z$-transform of a filter" in my paper. What would be the best symbol to be used for $Z$?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want another symbol than Z? What should it look like?

Comment: Use whatever is common in your field. I don't think there exists a law prescribing what the symbol should be.

Answer (score 2):

From [the Wikipedia Z-transform entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

The bilateral or two-sided Z-transform of a discrete-time signal $x[n]$ is the formal power series $X(z)$ defined as
\[
X(z)=\mathcal{Z}\{x[n]\}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]z^{-n}
\]
where $n$ is an integer and $z$ is, in general, a complex number:

\end{document}
```